# How to reference System.Net.Http in WP8?

Tags: c#, http, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am relatively new to WP8 development and have come across a problem that i just cannot figure out, even after hours of googling.

I am using visual studio 2012 and have implemented System.Net.Http using NuGet, have checked references, copy local is set to true, but it will not build.

This is the error message which greets me:

```
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module '3D Protect Premium': Could not resolve member reference: [System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]System.Net.Http.HttpClient::PostAsync.  [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)
```

How do i fix this so the referenced version is correct??

**Edit**

Code added below. This doesnt seem to be problematic, its just the referencing - i think its me misunderstanding to be honest, i Just dont have a clue whats going on with the System.Net.Http assembly!!

```
//Creates a new HttpClient Instance
            var client = new HttpClient();

            // This is the postdata
            // Data forms an array and is used to populate the remote MySQL DB
            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "windowsphonetest"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("latitude", LatitudeString));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("longitude ", LongitudeString));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("devID", "test"));


            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

            //The actual HTTP Transaction
            client.PostAsync("http://blah.com", content).ContinueWith(
                (postTask) =>
                {
                    postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `System.Net.Http` package you're trying to use has been deprecated but you can use [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) instead.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thank you. Now though it says Net does not exist in the Microsoft namespace?

Comment: I believe the namespace remains `System.Net.Http`.

Comment: So how do i reference it? I am still getting the above error wen i use the Microsoft.Net.Http package.

Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks, i checked dependencies and that seemed to help to an extent (different error message) but what seemed to be the cure was to add a binding redirect. My server now shows the data is being sent from my phone. This has driven me crazy...Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome :) It may be worthwhile to post your solution as an answer and then accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: Okay, suddenly it has stopped playing nice and will not build. I'm going insane here. Ive re-referenced everything and just cannot figure out the problem...would really appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Comment: I haven't used it myself buy happy to try and help. Are you getting the same error message? Would it be possible to post the `HttpClient` code (with the destination address hidden if need be) in your original question so that I can try it out on my machine?

Comment: Thank you ever so much. As I say, this is a new platform for me and some things are proving rather elusive. I have gotten to grips with things quite quickly but this is irritating me!

Comment: Not sure if this is good or bad but your code is working fine for me :) I created a new WP8 project, added reference to Microsoft.Net.Http (via the NuGet packet manager in VS), pasted your code and I get a response back with no errors. Did you add the package via the NuGet manager?

Comment: I did, but when i go to build, I get an error from 'code analysis' telling me it couldn't resolve the System.Net.Http assembly. Thank you for trying! Strangely, IntelliSense suggests the .Http namespace, so it surely recognizes its presence...very confused!

Comment: No problem :) This isn't an answer but could you get away with using `Webclient` or `HttpWebRequest` directly or is the `HttpClient` required?

Comment: Okay - The problem seems to be the code analysis tool itself - Disabling code analysis on build fixes the issue. Project builds fine and runs okay on my handset (Lumia 920).

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working! :) Not sure why the tool isn't compatible but this release but at least there's a workaround.

Comment: Very odd indeed, most likely my own doing, but can hopefully cope without it!!

Thank you for all your help. This website makes me want to develop an e-Beer service...

Comment: Happy to help! Could trade in reps for beer although I foresee quality of answers going down as rep goes up :D

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Delete all dependent NuGet packages, cleaning solution, deleting references to System.Net.* assemblies.

Install Microsoft.Net.Http and its dependencies as suggested by NuGet. Then install Microsoft.Bcl.Async - this is a dependency which is not flagged by NuGet (thanks keyboardP)

Now go into project properties and disable 'Code analysis on build' - this tool is tripping up over the version number for some reason. Now the code builds and deploys fine.