# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' in WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have this error in downloaded Windows Phone 8 app.
It is declared as

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Seems like it must to work. How to make this work?

Comment: Related : [How to reference System.Net.Http in WP8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393889/how-to-reference-system-net-http-in-wp8)

Answer (score 0):

It is valid actually you have to install the Nuget package of `System.Net.Http`.

- You can try Enable `Nuget Package Restore` in the solution. You can
  do that by Right Click On Solution => Select Enable Nuget package
  restore.
- You can also achieve that by go Manage Nuget Packages e.g Project=>
  Manage Nuget Packages => Search Online `System.Net.Http` => Install
  the package.

Update Nuget Package :-

Tools=> Extensions and Updates => Updates. then update your Nuget.

Done :)

Comment: It tells that my nuget manager too old. I need to update it first.